# Components of any topological space X form a partition of X

Tags: general-topology

A Space $X$ is connected if every continuous map $f: X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is constant. Any maximal connected subset of X will be called a connected component.

The following fact is stated in [this wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space):

"The components of any topological space X form a partition of X: they are disjoint, non-empty, and their union is the whole space."

Now I understand the disjoint part. What I do not understand is why they are

a) non-empty
b) their union is the whole space

Would appreciate your help :)

Comment: What is your definition of a component?

Comment: Sorry you are right, edited my post.

Comment: The "maximal" property implies that they are non-empty, and that every points must be contained in one of the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Some authors exclude the topology on $\varnothing$ from being connected (this doesn't seem to be your case, though): for these authors $\varnothing$ cannot be a connected subset in the first place. This is consistent with the notion that $\varnothing$ is the only [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $\varnothing$. For the authors according to whom $\varnothing$ *is* connected, the definition of component you've given implies that $\varnothing$ cannot be a connected component in a non-empty topological space: given some $x\in X$, $\varnothing\subsetneq \{x\}$ and $\{x\}$ is connected. However, with that definition and $\varnothing$ connected, we have that in the empty space the set of connected components is $\{\varnothing\}$, which is incidentally not a partition of $\varnothing$.
2. The central lemma you want to look at is:

   > Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal F$ be a non-empty family of connected subsets of $X$ such that $\bigcap\mathcal F\ne \varnothing$. Then, $\bigcup\mathcal F$ is connected.
   >
   > *Sketch of proof:* If $U,V$ are open such that $U\cup V\supseteq \bigcup \mathcal F$, then by connectness the one that intersects non-trivially $\bigcap\mathcal F$ must cover each of the sets of the family $\mathcal F$.

   Every $x\in X$ is then contained in the connected set $\bigcup\{H\subseteq X\,:\, H\text{ connected}\land x\in H\}$. Notice that $\{x\}$ is connected.